# How to remove element from iterator if condition depends on property of the object the iterator is based on?

Tags: kotlin, iterator, iteration

Let me elaborate:

I need to be able to iterate over a list of objects. Each of the objects has a property which is a list, and I have to check if that list contains any elements that are not in another list.

When I tried to do it by using nested for loops, it kept giving me concurrent modification exceptions, so I tried to use an iterator, but now I'm stuck, since if I make an iterator based on the list of objects, I can't access the individual object's properties to then iterate over.

Here's some example code of what I was trying to accomplish:

```kotlin
for (preference in preferencesWithRestaurant) {
    for (restaurantID in preference.restaurantIDs) {
        // One method I tried using
        preferencesWithRestaurant.removeIf{ !listOfIds.contains(restaurantID) }

        /* alternate method I tried using
        if (!listOfIds.contains(restaurantID)) {
            preferencesWithRestaurant.remove(preference)
        }
        */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can replace the value of `preferencesWithRestaurant` or store the result in another variable then you can [filter it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html):

```kotlin
preferencesWithRestaurant = preferencesWithRestaurant.filter { preference ->
    preference.restaurantIDs.all { it in listOfIds }
}
```

Depending on the exact type of `preferencesWithRestaurant` you may need to convert it to the proper type, e.g. invoke `toMutableList()` at the end.

If you prefer to modify `preferencesWithRestaurant` in-place, then you can use [retainAll()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/retain-all.html) (thanks @Tenfour04):

```kotlin
preferencesWithRestaurant.retainAll { preference ->
    preference.restaurantIDs.all { it in listOfIds }
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your original approach, but use a mutable iterator to remove an item while iterating:

```kotlin
val iter = preferencesWithRestaurant.listIterator()
for (preference in iter) {
    for (restaurantID in preference.restaurantIDs) {
        if (!listOfIds.contains(restaurantID)) {
            iter.remove()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you! I actually just learned about filtering in javascript, so it's interesting that kotlin has such similar functionality.

Comment: @TheQ614 Filtering is a fairly standard operation in [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages — and more recently, ideas from those have spread into other programming languages. In particular, [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) was explicitly designed to combine the object-oriented style (from languages like Java) with the functional style (from languages like Scheme); and in turn Scala was one of the major influences on Kotlin.